# Network Theorems on DC and AC

Tags: circuit-analysis

Are network theorems (KVL, KCL, Thevenin, Norton, Superposition, Max Power Transfer) applicable on both DC and AC networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AC network is just a linearised (around an operating point) version of
the circuit, so the results apply. (Allowing for the fact that resistances may become impedances, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so long as the lumped circuit approximation is valid (or close enough for the case at hand).